# Why session message is not working Fat-free-framework?

Tags: session, fat-free-framework

I wrote a sample crud application and want to show some messages if successful or if error occurs. But when I tried to set a session message it does not displayed to the page after redirect. It also doesn't exists in $_SESSION.

Here is my code in UsersController

```
public function index(){
    $user = new User($this->db);
    $this->f3->set('users',$user->all());
    $this->f3->set('page_head','User List');
    //get session 
    new Session();
    $sess= $this->f3->get('SESSION.test');
    //set it to use in view file
    $this->f3->set('message', $sess);
    $this->f3->set('view','users/list.htm');
}

public function create(){
    if($this->f3->exists('POST.create')){
        $user = new User($this->db);
        $user->add();
        //set session 
        new Session();
        $this->f3->set('SESSION.test',"Success");
        $this->f3->reroute('/users');
    } else{
        $this->f3->set('page_head','Create User');
        $this->f3->set('view','users/create.htm');
    }
}
```

and here is my view file.

```
      <check if="{{ @message }}">
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <strong>{{ @message }}</strong>
        </div>
```

Its not working. What's wrong with this? Codes are taken from [fat free framework](http://fatfreeframework.com/session)

Edit: As xfra35 suggested

Ok, when i used

`$f3->set('SESSION.test','Success');`

and removed call to

> new Session();

this works fine but how to use it directly in layout file instead of setting a message variable in controller to pass it to layout file? I mean should I remove these lines

> $sess= $this->f3->get('SESSION.test');
> $this->f3->set('message', $sess);

and can use this session message directly in view file. I need to set session message like this

> $_SESSION['msg']['success']="Updated";
>
> or $_SESSION['msg']['error']="Error";

I need to loop through session message and view if its error message or success message. Is there any way to make session variable blank once they displayed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Session class you're using is a **cache-based** session handler.

If no in-memory cache backend (APC, Memcache, Redis, XCache etc..) is found on your server, the framework will use its own filesystem-based cache system. In that case, the files are stored in a subfolder named `cache/` inside the `TEMP` folder.
(see [here](http://fatfreeframework.com/cache) for more details on F3's cache engine)

So to answer your question: there are chances that the `TEMP` folder is **not writable**.

Anyway if you don't explicitly need to store sessions in cache, just remove calls to the Session class and keep using `$f3->set('SESSION.test')`: session will be stored on filesystem by PHP (classic behavior).

Here are the various ways of storing sessions in F3:

**Default PHP session (filesystem):**

```
$f3->set('SESSION.test','Success');
```

**Cache storage:**

```
new Session();
$f3->set('SESSION.test','Success');
```

**SQL storage:**

```
$db=new DB\SQL($dsn,$user,$pw);
new DB\SQL\Session($db);
$f3->set('SESSION.test','Success');
```

**MongoDB storage:**

```
$db=new DB\Mongo($dsn,$dbname);
new DB\Mongo\Session($db);
$f3->set('SESSION.test','Success');
```

**JigDB storage:**

```
$db=new DB\Jig($dir);
new DB\Jig\Session($db);
$f3->set('SESSION.test','Success');
```

Comment: Can you please make a new question out of it? These are 2 different topics and we should think about people seeking a clear answer to a clear question ;)

Comment: What I mean is that your 2nd question is not specific to session variables. It could apply to any variable.

Comment: thanks @ xfra35. I just commented that line and ecerything works fine but I just want to know if there is any way to pass session variable directly to view instead of setting through controller's method.

Comment: Once again, your question is a bit vague and would require a dedicated topic. If what you need is reading a session variable from within a view, then the [$SESSION](http://fatfreeframework.com/quick-reference#COOKIE,GET,POST,REQUEST,SESSION,FILES,SERVER,ENV) variable is already there for you. If what you need is a flash messaging system, then you can find some inputs on the [F3 Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/f3-framework) or ask your question there.

Comment: My apologies. I just want to show some message on success or error. Nothing else. But at the same time i want to know if it is success or error message in view file. Thanks for your valuable answer. I think you are one of f3 core developer. You guys shpuld make function for flash messages.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed explanation, I was stuck trying to get the session variable to work.

Answer (score 0):

One scenario i came across is if the object we are storing into `session` is not serializable. e.g. model class which extends `pdo`. unfortunately, no error message is shown if this is left to the default handling. putting an explicit session_commit() in the code will then display such errors.

The other causes are  : the session_save_path() is not writable by user running the web server, or sometimes redirects may prevent cookies being set.